# R by() round stat.desc

Tags: r, statistics, rounding

I am concerned about the following question. If I apply the function

```
by(productivity$LOC, productivity$extension, stat.desc, norm = TRUE, basic = TRUE)
```

how can I round the output values of the by() function?

Comment: Try `by(productivity$LOC, productivity$extension, function(X) round(stat.desc(X, norm = TRUE, basic = TRUE),1))` (untested). And then you can use `do.call(cbind.data.frame, r)` to put the results in a dataframe (where `r` is the result of your `by` function)

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks a lot, works perfectly! I know that an another solution would be to store all the values of applying stat.desc to each category inside of a for loop, and then printing those. But this is definitely a more elegant solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly pass the value to the function by defining the `FUN=function()` value.

Using the `mtcars` dataset

```
library(pastecs)
```

Note that the first line is an abbreviated version of the second

```
by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am, stat.desc, norm = TRUE, basic = TRUE) 
by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am, function(X)  stat.desc(X, norm = TRUE, basic = TRUE))
```

Using the second method to pass multiple functions to the `by` function

```
result <- by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am, function(X)  
                           round(stat.desc(X, norm = TRUE, basic = TRUE), 1))
```

You can then put the result in a dataframe

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, result)
```